# Check to see if a SQL Insert was successful using Perl

Tags: sql, perl

I have a script that uses Perl to insert data into a database like this:

```
$SQL = "INSERT into database (title,time,etc) VALUES ('$title','$time','$etc')";
eval {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
  }; 

  # check for errors
  if($@){
    $dbh->disconnect;
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "An ERROR occurred! $@\n";
    exit;
  } else {
    $sth->execute;
  } # end of if/else
  return ($sth);
}
```

Despite escaping offending characters, sometimes users copy and paste data from a PDF which causes the insert command to fail.  How can I quickly check to make sure that the insert command was successful and if not, display an error?

Comment: What values do you use for RaiseError and PrintError?

Answer (score 4):

Check the return value from [`execute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute). If it's undef, there was an error.

Some people like to set the `PrintError` or `RaiseError` attributes for their handles. The first gives you a warning and the second throws an exception.

But, as Andy said, also use placeholders. These will use the values properly so you don't have to worry about quoting, special characters, and the like:

```
my $SQL = "INSERT into database (title,time,etc) VALUES (?,?,?)";
...
my $rv = $sth->execute( $title, $time, $etc );
if( ! defined $rv ) { warn "Oops! $DBI::Error" }
```

Those placeholders can also constrain its values (backend support varies). For example, you can specify that it must be an integer. Look for `bind_values` in the docs.

See [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com) for some fun times.

Comment: Thank you!  This is helpful.  I'll have to play with it awhile.  I've been going mad trying to escape characters.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use prepared statements and bind variables.  You should not create SQL statements using input from users.

Read [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) in the docs about placeholders and bind values.